# How do I cd into a hard drive with a GPT partition table using a raspberry pi running raspbian?

Tags: hard-disk, gpt

My ubuntu laptop has died, and so I am attempting to recover some files off the hard drive using a raspberry pi. I have removed my laptop's hard drive and attached it to my raspberry pi via usb. I am now trying to figure out how I can `cd` into it to view my files.

online, various forums say to use `sudo fdisk -l` but this apparently cannot read GPT. When I run the command, a message says "The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted."

Gparted is a graphical application. I would like a way to do this using the terminal alone.

I do not wish to modify the hard drive, only read from it.

How can I do this and access my files?

**Update:** So I figured out `sudo parted -l` outputs

```
Model: ST500LT0 32-1E9142 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   492GB  491GB   ext4
 3      492GB   500GB  8483MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

I want to cd into the 492GB partition. I tried `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` but that gives me

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `parted` is different from `gparted`. Have you tried to have a look?

Comment: "parted -l" isn't printing anything out for some reason

Comment: What does `sudo file -s /dev/sda?` print?

Comment: See the edit to my question. parted - l wasn't printing anything because I wasn't using sudo

Comment: What happens when you do `fsck -N /dev/sda2` (the `-N` prevents it from changing anything, which is a bad idea if the file system is corrupted)? Does it complain about errors?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu was it? Do you know what filesystem type you used? It seems it might not be ext4; perhaps it's xfs? Or maybe there's disk encryption involved?

Answer (score 1):

Using `parted` is fairly straightforward. The man page doesn't give examples but it's quite readable. Really. Here's a safe example for you:

```
parted /dev/sdb unit MiB print
```

Once you have this information you still need to mount the various filesystems.

```
mkdir /mnt/part              # Adjust to suit
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/part    # You might need /dev/sdb2, /dev/sdb3, etc.
cd /mnt/part
...
cd
umount /mnt/part
```

These will be read/write mounts. If you want to mount read-only then include the `-r` flag - `mount -r /dev/sdb1 /mnt/part`, etc.

Comment: okay, so "sudo parted -l" outputs 

 Model: ST500LT0 32-1E9142 (scsi)
 Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
 Partition Table: gpt

 Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
  1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
  2      538MB   492GB  491GB   ext4
  3      492GB   500GB  8483MB  linux-swap(v1)

I want to access the 492GB volume. I try "sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt" but that says "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error" What am I doing wrong

Comment: @quantumbutterfly yes, on all block devices. You asked for one so I gave you options for one.

Comment: okay, I tried to comment the error this is giving me, but comments don't support formatting or line breaks, so I edited it into my main question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sgdisk utility, sgdisk supports GPT.

To list the partition table

```
  sgdisk -p /dev/<dev-node>
```

Comment: how do I install sgdisk?

Comment: You can try Ubuntu MATE, you can use the apt package manager to install sgdisk.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can, build your own sgdisk from sources.